# Enabling VPN kill switch shows no internet

Tags: vpn, windows-10

When I enable kill switch on a VPN client on Windows 10, I see no Internet sign on the task bar.

[image]

However, I have Internet connectivity and I can browse the Internet with Chrome, Firefox or Edge. The problem here is that some applications such as Spotify think that there is no Internet connectivity and are shown as offline.

I tried both Nord and Express VPNs and I am getting the same exact behavior.
I noticed that enabling kill switch adds a new entry to the host routing table with a low metric that forces all traffic to get forwarded to the VPN interface. This might be the reason behind why Windows thinks that there is no Internet connectivity. So my questions are:

1. How Windows figure out if it is connected to the Internet
2. How I can fix the issue to be able to use an application like Spotify that thinks that its offline.

Comment: I had the same problem with another VPN provider. I solved by configure the client to ignore all IPv6 trafic and forcing all DNS queries to the VPN DNS server. I've also added the VPN client to the allowed programs in the MS Firewall...

Answer (score 0):

The internet indicator is Microsoft's way of essentially telling if you can reach a particular Microsoft service or not, not necessarily if you can get on the internet in general. When you use one of these VPN services, you are routing all of your traffic (including DNS) through the gateway and DNS provided by the VPN, which could come out of any VPN endpoint the provider has chosen, perhaps in another country, and after taking several hops. All of this bouncing around provides you with some anonymity, but also increases latency and reduces available bandwidth. Spotify is latency sensitive and requires a fair bit of bandwidth due to the way their service delivers content. You may not be able to use it over a VPN. Spotify could also be blocked by the VPN DNS servers, or the country of your VPN endpoint, or Spotify could be blocking you because it sees you browsing from a VPN, or there could just not be enough bandwidth. You may be able to get around Spotify's blocks by manipulating your hosts file, dns records, routing tables, or some combination of all of these tricks, but I think you are going to be mostly on your own trying to figure that out. Personally, I use a VM for any VPN traffic, which isolates it from my main PC, and ensures that I can still access the internet normally from my main PC, while connected to a VPN through the VM.

More reading on Network Connectivity Indicator: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc766017(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_How